# Powershell Select-String Matches

Tags: powershell

I have a log that I am searching for a particular string ("the timeout period"). I can use the following to pick up instances of this in my log:

```
Get-Content mylog.txt | select-string 'the timeout period' | select-object
```

The problem that I'm having is that this is an XML file an powershell is only picking up the line with the error, while I really need the data/time info. What I need is a line instance matching "thread" just before the line instance matching 'the timeout period'. For instance:

```
Thread 3423 - 6:34:00
Info following. ..... ....
Error .... the timeout period
```

So what I want to output is:

```
Thread 3423 - 6:34:00
```

Comment: It could be done with this, but you're saying that it is actually an xml file? Can we get a sample of it? If the data is seperated in different elements in an xml, it's way easier.

Comment: I realized that it's not actually XML, it's just formatted in such a way that makes it difficult to filter lines because they run together.

Comment: Check out the answer I provided. Should work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the info part can be multiple lines. So this is my attempt:

```
$content = Get-Content .\test.txt
$content | select-string "the timeout period" | % {
    $i = ($_.linenumber -1)

    while ($content[$i] -notlike "Thread*") {
        $i--
    }

    $content[$i]
}
```

It displays the previous line starting with "Thread" for each error. Ex. output:

```
Thread 3423 - 1:34:00
Thread 3423 - 2:34:00
Thread 3423 - 3:34:00
Thread 3423 - 4:34:00
```

Comment: This one created some duplicate entries. I used get-unique to clean them up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is XML I would consider using Select-Xml and an XPath search pattern.  That said, you can use Select-String like so:

```
Get-Content mylog.txt | select-string "the timeout period" -context 2 | 
    Foreach {$_.Context.PreContext[0]}
```

Comment: This is close but there a few examples where context doesn't reach to the "Thread" line. To get all thread info I had to push it back to -Context 5. This works but is not very accurate As I am getting an additional line as well.